# Adobe Cirrus Error on Direct Connect"Property startTransmit not found on flash.net.NetStream"

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-media-server, adobe-cirrus

The error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property startTransmit not found on flash.net.NetStream and there is no default value.
```

I've played around with cirrus plenty of times before and have yet to see this error before. But now I cant get it to go away.

My p2p Direct connect works great just fine. But every single time i see this error pop up. It throws an exception. I can't figure out where it's exactly happening.

Has anyone encountered this before? Any ideas where I should look?

Comment: Could you show the code, where you initialize netconnection and netstream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every client object needs to have the following functions defined.

```
client.stopTransmit=function($p1:*,$p2:*):void{
    trace("stopTransmit called",$p1,$p2);
}
client.startTransmit=function():void{
    trace("startTransmit called");
}
```

For example, set these in the `onPeerConnect` function:

```
sendStream.client = new Object();
sendStreamClient.onPeerConnect = function(subscriber:NetStream): Boolean{
    var client:Object=new Object();
    client.stopTransmit=function($p1:*,$p2:*):void{
        trace("stopTransmit called",$p1,$p2);
    }
    client.startTransmit=function():void{
        trace("startTransmit called");
    }
    subscriber.client=farStreamClient;
}
```

Additionally these need to be set on your sendStreamClient's `client` property:

```
sendStreamClient.client.stopTransmit=function($p1:*,$p2:*):void{
    trace("stopTransmit called",$p1,$p2);
}
sendStreamClient.client.startTransmit=function():void{
    trace("startTransmit called");
}
```

And they need to be set on your recieveStreamClient's `client` property.

Comment: I've just suddenly started running into this error as well, but now it's very consistent.  Why are people going for months without seeing it a single time, then suddenly running into it 100% of the time like this?

Comment: Evidently it's somewhat linked to whether one of the clients is using certain sub-versions of Flash Player 11, as opposed to other sub-versions.

Answer (score 1):

On the server side script, you probably (or somebody else) have set up the application, so that it calls back a function -this time it is startTransmit-, and it isn't handled on the client side.
Remove the code from the server, or add a default value, or add a function to your code.

In my similar program, i had to add the function to my code (in my case it was not 'startTransmit') :

```
if ("NetConnection.Connect.Success" == e.info.code) {
netConnection.client=new Object();
netConnection.client.startTransmit=startTransmit; //no columns!
}
```

where startTransmit is

```
private function startTransmit():Boolean{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending h264 videos? I think it is to do with that...

If you add

```
public function startTransmit($p1:*,$p2:*):void{

}

public function stopTransmit():void{

}
```

where you have your media server connection it should work fine, at least it does for me :)

Comment: I'm making an AIR Android project, its happening when the phone is put to sleep for a moment, and when its waking back up. I'm able to suppress them on my receiveStream using those functions you posted like that. But not on my sendStream, its strange because I have the client properly pointing to these functions in the sendStream just the way I do in my receiveStream. Any ideas?

Comment: If you paste a snippet of your code I could have a look, however from what you are saying it does seem abit odd.  Have you tried asking/looking around the adobe forums / Bugbase?

Answer (score 0):

There is another netstream other than receiveStream and sendStream. You should set `startTransmit` and `stopTransmit` functions on the **callerns** netstream, something like this:

```
sendStreamClient.onPeerConnect = function(callerns:NetStream): Boolean{
    var farStreamClient:Object=new Object();
    farStreamClient.stopTransmit=function($p1:*,$p2:*):void{
        trace("-------------farStream stopTransmit called!",$p1,$p2);
    }
    farStreamClient.startTransmit=function():void{
        trace("-------------farStream startTransmit called!");
    }
    callerns.client=farStreamClient;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not on AMS or Red5 server. Even transmitting a video on P2P from an Android device triggers the same error.
The solution worked.
Actually the stopTransmit() sends a Boolean and an integer.
It would be amazing to know what they mean.
I have opened a bug on adobe bugbase in order to have it documented or removed.
Please vote:
https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3844856